# how to use pyknackhq python library for getting whole objects/tables from my knack builder

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to connect [knack](https://builder.knack.com/) online database with my python data handling scripts in order to renew objects/tables directly into my knack app builder. I discovered [pyknackhq](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyknackhq) Python API for KnackHQ can fetch objects and return json objects for the object's records. So far so good.

However, following the documentation (http://www.wbh-doc.com.s3.amazonaws.com/pyknackhq/quick%20start.html) I have tried to fetch all rows (records in knack) for my object-table (having in total 344 records). 
My code was:

```
i =0
for rec in undec_obj.find():
    print(rec)
    i=i+1
print(i)

>> 25
```

All first 25 records were returned indeed, however the rest until the 344-th were never returned. The documentation of pyknackhq library is relatively small so I couldn't find a way around my problem there. Is there a solution to get all my records/rows? (I have also changed the specification in knack to have all my records appear in the same page - page 1).

The ultimate goal is to take all records and make them a pandas dataframe.
thank you!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that library. However, I did notice that you mentioned that it returns json objects. have you looked at [pandas.read_json](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html)? This should be able to create the dataframes for you

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I know how to make the dataframes from json. It is not where the major problem lies in, it is when I try to receive all records from knack. Unfortunately it must be the only library available to directly connect Python and Knack. Thanks!

Comment: Can you incrementally pull all the records and then append them into one data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with that library, but I've written another python Knack API wrapper that should help:
https://github.com/cityofaustin/knackpy

The docs should get you where you want to go. Here's an example:

```
>>> from knackpy import Knack

#  download data from knack object
#  will fetch records in chunks of 1000 until all records have been downloaded
#  optionally pass a rows_per_page and/or page_limit parameter to limit record count
>>> kn = Knack( 
        obj='object_3',
        app_id='someappid',
        api_key='topsecretapikey',
        page_limit=10,  #  not needed; this is the default
        rows_per_page=1000  #  not needed; this is the default
    )

>>> for row in kn.data:
        print(row)

{'store_id': 30424, 'inspection_date': 1479448800000, 'id': '58598262bcb3437b51194040'},...
```

Hope that helps. Open a GitHub issue if you have any questions using the package.

Comment: Thanks!! I'll definately try it out!